# What features of V8 engine dose Node.js use when implementing ECMAScript modules

Tags: node.js

Unlike CommonJS module, ECMAScript module is specified by ECMAScript Language Specification. After V8 engine implements ECMAScript module, Node.js also implements ECMAScript module. Node.js is based on V8 engine, so I want to know what features of V8 engine dose Node.js take advantage of when implementing ECMAScript module.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but here you go:

V8 natively implements ECMAScript modules through `v8::Isolate::SetHostImportModuleDynamicallyCallback` and `v8::Isolate::SetHostInitializeImportMetaObjectCallback`.

These callbacks are called when v8 parses an import of the style `import ... from ...`. NodeJS then does some module resolution internally and then does a module import:

```cpp
// 1. Compile the module
auto module = v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileModule(...).ToLocalChecked();
// 2. Instantiate the module
module->InstantiateModule(context, ResolveCallback).ToChecked();
// 3. Evaluate the module
module->Evaluate(context).ToLocalChecked();
```

This is just the VERY basic concept. If you want a more extensive (but still simplistic) example, look [here](https://gist.github.com/surusek/4c05e4dcac6b82d18a1a28e6742fc23e).